# Who resets the email address that I'm locked out of?

Tags: pokemon-go

My grandson created a Pokemon Go acct on my Iphone some time ago using his school email address and tried too many time to log in yesterday. The acct is now temporarily disabled saying to contact the administrator. Who resets the acct? The school, Google or Niantic?

The message is "This Google account has been disabled" And beside that is a hyperlink that says Learn More.  When I click that is where is says "Account access temporarily disabled by an administrator. But the email address used was originally used to create the account is a school email address.

Comment: Could you possibly add an image of the notification (assuming no personal details are displayed)? My guess is that it's the school, since it's his *school* email address.

Comment: I would like to clarification on this as well, saying to contact administrator does not sound like something that you would get from an IOS game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about identifying who administers an email address, which isn't a gaming issue.

Comment: I'm sorry Frank. Since I can't login to a game, I thought this was a good forum. My apologies if I am on the wrong board.

Comment: If you were asking how to get into the game, that we could help with. Identifying who controls an email address is well outside our jurisdiction.

Answer (score 5):

Since it is a school account that appears to be hosted under the auspices of Gmail, I should note that Gmail has a very modular interface for schools that enable them to turn off certain features deemed non-essential. My university administered our @univeristyName address through Gmail, and while Google Drive was enabled, Youtube wasn't. I suspect something similar has happened here, perhaps to do with using it for mobile OAuth authentication, and it'd be best for your grandson to confirm with the school's IT. It is unlikely anything can be done by anyone else, and unfortunately, unlikely that the school are willing to reduce any restrictions for recreation.

Comment: Thank you Rome_Leader. Just a note, the email address is XXX@countystudents.org.  Not sure if you I led you to believe that it was a xxxschoolxxx@gmail.com email account.  Again thanks.

Comment: No problem. When I say 'hosted by Gmail', it doesn't have to have an @gmail.com ending. My university address ended with '@myuniversity.ca', but it was just an alias for a Gmail account provided by Google for Education: https://www.google.com/edu/products/productivity-tools/